# Is there a way of creating an instance of an object for each client in a gRPC Server?

Tags: .net, .net-core, grpc, .net-4.8, grpc-dotnet

I am creating a grpc client-server project. For every client I want to instatiate a different object:

My client class looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001,SslCredentials.Insecure);

            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            var client2 = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

            String user = "Alice";
            String user2 = "Bob";

            var reply = client.putName(new HelloRequest { Name = user });
            Console.WriteLine(reply.Message);
            var reply2 = client2.putName(new HelloRequest { Name = user2 });
            Console.WriteLine(reply2.Message);

            reply = client.getName();
            Console.WriteLine(reply.Message);
            reply2 = client2.getName();
            Console.WriteLine(reply2.Message);

            reply = client.modifyName(new HelloRequest { Name = "Frank" });
            Console.WriteLine(reply.Message);
            reply2 = client2.modifyName(new HelloRequest { Name = "Russel" });
            Console.WriteLine(reply2.Message);
}
```

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private IName n;
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger,IName n)
    {
        this.n = n;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override Task<HelloReply> putName(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        n.SetName(request.Name);
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "User changed"
            });
    }

    public override Task<HelloReply> getName(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = this.name
        });
    }
    public override Task<HelloReply> modifyName(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        string new_name= n.SetName(request.Name);
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + new_name
            });
    }
}
```

I also added `services.AddSingleton<IName>(new Name("name"));` to the **ConfigureServices** method in **Startup.cs**.

The result of running my client is:

```
> User changed
> User changed
> Bob
> Bob
> Hello Frank
> Hello Russel
```

Instead, I want the server to keep an instance of each `Name` objects with the resulting output:

```
> User changed
> User changed
> Alice
> Bob
> Hello Frank
> Hello Russel
```

Is this possible using gRPC?

Comment: By "every client" do you mean for each connection (so if a client disconnects and reconnects they are treated as a new client) or are you looking for some form of session management (the client informs the server who it is at connection or uses some form of authentication).

Comment: I mean every connection

Comment: When configuring the service in ASP.NET Core (regardless whether is a gRPC service or not) you can choose the service lifetime according to your needs. See e.g https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/migration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#grpc-service-implementation-lifetime and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes. It is up to you to choose with of the service lifetimes (Transient, Scoped, Singleton) works the best for your app.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked with:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TYPEOFSERVICE>()
```

inside of the Startup or Program.cs

instead of

```
services.AddSingleton<IName>(new Name("name"))
```